# Laravel Vue component not working

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, laravel-5.4, vue-component

I am using Laravel 5.4 and trying to implement vue.js. I have created a component like this :

```
    <template>
     <li>This is a list item</li>
   </template>

<script>
    export default {
        ready() {
            console.log('Component ready.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

and saved it as `Chat.vue` in `components` folder.

Then in `app.js`:

```
Vue.component('chat', require('./components/Chat.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Trying to use it in view:

```
<div id="app">

<chat></chat>

</div>
```

But I don't get the expected view.I should get a `<li>` but nothing.BLANK!!!
Don't get any message in console.I have searched through internet for last three hours to get a solution.I have cleared my cache and disabled cache in chrome. Nothing happened.I also tried in firefox but no luck.

Another problem is I have deleted `Example.vue`  from the components folder.But when I am using `<example>` in my view, it's still working.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have called the `app.js` file in the webpack.mix.js file, right?

This syntax looks good, but why not try it the way it is documented, so like this:

before:
`Vue.component('chat', require('./components/Chat.vue'));`

after:
`import Chat from './components.Chat'; Vue.component('chat', Chat);`

Comment: I have solved the problem.I had to run npm run dev command.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. Run `npm run watch` to watch it.